# Who tweets for tex.sx – and how would I know if I have been tweeted?

Tags: support, questions, social-networking

Please forgive my ignorance of tweeting, twitter, and other words matching tw.*

I was editing one of my previous questions, and noticed that it had been tweeted

[image: tweet]

This also happened to one of my recent answers, which I discovered by accident again while viewing the edits.

So, to the questions:

- Who tweets them officially for tex.sx?
- How do I know what has been tweeted other than by viewing the editing history?

Just for fun: John Cleese apparently calls his followers 'twots'.

Comment: I'm also curious about it. `:)` By the way, we need a [tag:john-cleese] tag.

Comment: I guess you need to follow this thingy on twitter : https://twitter.com/StackTeX and the tweets are done based on some algorithm probably and who knows what it is. Some show up as *can you answer this?* some comes out as *great answer* so there is more to it than just randomly tweeting questions.

Comment: @percusse if you have a reference, then your comment sounds like an answer :)

Comment: See [Twitter Question Feeds for Stack Exchange](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/twitter-question-feeds-for-stack-exchange/) and the comments, as a reference.

Comment: @StefanKottwitz that sounds like the answer to my first question- thanks! :) how would I know if I have been tweeted though? I suppose that would make me a tweetee? :)

Comment: @cmhughes To get a comprehensive answer, it might be helpful to edit this question to be applicable to any site in the SE network and migrate it to [metase].

Comment: @doncherry yes, that's a good idea- how would I migrate it? Presumably I'd need a moderator to do it....

Comment: @cmhughes Yes, I don't think we have a migration path to [metase] here, so you'll need to flag your post for moderator attention. But since folks are comparably aggressive about closing posts over there (or migrating them back), I'd ensure the question's network-wide applicability there, and also that your question focuses on something that's not already explained in the blog post Stefan hinted to.

Comment: Related (virtually identical) post on Meta.SO without answer: [Is there a way to check if a post has been sent to Twitter?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80069/168244)